# How do I separate what value is stored in a single byte (of a long)?

Tags: java

I'm currently attempting to learn how to solve a problem for an assignment.

• The class stores the hours worked, `hours`, a long, being a packed version of the hours

- an hour entry is between 0.0 and 24.0 (one decimal place)
- an hour entry * 10 is between 0 and 240. Conveniently it fits into an unsigned byte.
- a long can hold 8 bytes.
- `hours` is a long with the least significant 7 bytes set to the scaled hour entries (or decihours if that helps). Hours for Saturday are stored in the right-most byte: the format looks like 00-FR-TH-WE-TU-MO-SU-SA, where each two letters represents one byte, from high to low.

My question is, how would I go about doing this? How do I store a certain value between 0 and 240 at a certain byte location in a long, and make sure they stay separate?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java does not have unsigned types. Declare a `long` for each day of the week. Use the [operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) to shift each day's value to the desired byte position and then use [bit-wise] *or* to combine the day with another `long` variable that stores the entire week.

```java
long saturday = 17;
long sunday = 18;
long monday = 19;
long tuesday = 20;
long wednesday = 21;
long thursday = 22;
long friday = 23;
long week = (saturday * 10) | ((sunday * 10) << 8)
                            | ((monday * 10) << 16)
                            | ((tuesday * 10) << 24)
                            | ((wednesday * 10) << 32)
                            | ((thursday * 10) << 40)
                            | ((friday * 10) << 48);
```

In order to retrieve each day's value, perform the opposite actions on variable `week`. For example to retrieve the value for Monday, shift the value for `week` to the right so that the value for Monday occupies the least significant bits and then perform a [bit-wise] *and* to get the actual value. Since this value is multiplied by ten, simply divide by ten and you get the original value, as shown:

```java
long mon = ((week >> 16) & 0xFF) / 10;
```